# Add Hyperlink to Text in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, text, hyperlink, powerpoint

I am creating a powerpoint presentation for an interactive public display which has an index and clicking on the entry takes you to that specific slide.

I have done this by creating a text frame and then adding an hyperlink to the frame, but for some reason I cannot work out sometimes the links do not work.

Instead I would like to add the hyperlink to the actual text not the frame. I can do this manually but I have 4,500 links to create.

This is the code I use at the moment

```
Set sh = pp.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=leftcm, Top:=topcm, Width:=260, Height:=35)  
With sh.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)  
    .Action = ppActionHyperlink  
    .Hyperlink.SubAddress = "73. PowerPoint Presentation"  
End With  

sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "LEWIS, Arthur John"
```

I have only tried manually as I cannot work out how to change the code to just add the hyperlink to the text.

Comment: Have a look here (a PPT faq site that I maintain) for a fairly complete explanation of the .SubAddress property.https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00162_Hyperlink_-SubAddress_-_How_to_interpret_it.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead I would like to add the hyperlink to the actual text not the frame.

Is this you want?

```vb
Sub Add_Hyperlink_to_Text_in_Powerpoint()
    Dim sh As PowerPoint.Shape, pp As Presentation
    Const leftcm As Single = 0, topcm As Single = 0 'just for test
    
    Set pp = ActivePresentation
    
    Set sh = pp.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=leftcm, Top:=topcm, Width:=260, Height:=35)
'    With sh.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
'        .Action = ppActionHyperlink
'        .Hyperlink.SubAddress = "73. PowerPoint Presentation"
'    End With
    sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "LEWIS, Arthur John"
    
    With sh.TextFrame.TextRange.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
        .Action = ppActionHyperlink
        '.Hyperlink.Address = "https://www.google.com"
        .Hyperlink.SubAddress = "73. PowerPoint Presentation"
        .Hyperlink.TextToDisplay = sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Exactly what I want.

Comment: @Stephen Then would you mind to accept this answer to close your question?